# A loop within a loop in JavaScript

Tags: node.js, excel, exceljs

The solution to this may be simple but I cannot seem to think of an easier solution at present. I am using Excel.js and want to add values from an array to a specific set of cells. In this example `E6:E25`

The problem I face is that I cannot seem to select specific cells, only all of them in a column.

```
var array = ["4","3","3","3","3","8","2","4","5","2","2","6","4","3","8","5","4","3","2","2"]

workbook.xlsx.readFile('myFile.xlsx')
  .then(function() {
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    var column = worksheet.getColumn(5) // Selecting specific column
    column.eachCell(function(cell, rownumber){
      // eachCell count is 122, ideally not wanting to iterate 122 times
      // when only needing 20
      switch (cell['_address']) {
        case 'E6':
          worksheet.getCell(cell['_address']).value = array[0];
          break;
        case 'E7':
          worksheet.getCell(cell['_address']).value = array[1];
          break;
        case 'E8':
          worksheet.getCell(cell['_address']).value = array[2];
          break;
          // and so on 20 times
        default:
      }

    });

    return workbook.xlsx.writeFile('newFile.xlsx');
})
```

This is awful I know; I am looking to refactor this and make it a lot cleaner and efficient.

Comment: If everything is normalized, e.g., E6-E8...E*n*, then you just need to translate the 6-*n* to 0-*n*.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dave, not 100% sure on what you mean though sorry

Comment: worksheet.getCell('E8').value doesn't work?

Comment: You have a collection of cells. If they're ordered from E6-E*n* then you can translate the cell address (essentially an index) to array index by subtracting 6.

Comment: If it's not regular then it depends on what you actually need. Or you could use a map instead of an array with cellAddress => value, or you could rethink the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't a simple for loop like this do the same?

```
var array = ["4","3","3","3","3","8","2","4","5","2","2","6","4","3","8","5","4","3","2","2"];

for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    col = i+6;
    worksheet.getCell('E'+col).value = array[i];
}
```

Comment: @Richlewis Glad you worked it out, but that's what I said.

Comment: @DaveNewton apologies, couldn't see it in my head until i saw the code, appreciate you helping out